# Cannot mix different versions of joi schemas

Tags: javascript, node.js, joi

When trying to use `joi-password-complexity` package I get the following error:

Cannot mix different versions of joi schemas

My code:

```
const passwordComplexity = require('joi-password-complexity');

const complexityOptions = {
    min: 5,
    max: 20,
    lowerCase: 1,
    upperCase: 1,
    numeric: 0,
    symbol: 0,
    requirementCount: 2,
  };
```

```
        organization_id: Joi.string().required(),
        email: Joi.string().email().required(),
        password: passwordComplexity(complexityOptions),
        isVerified: Joi.boolean().default(false).required(),
        created_at: Joi.date().default(Date.now()).optional()
    }),
```

My package.json:
"joi": "^17.2.0",
"joi-password-complexity": "^4.2.0",

Comment: Where does `validation.joiUuid.optional()` come from?

Comment: Please proofread your post's title at least.

Comment: @weltschmerz what's wrong with the title sorry?

Comment: Nothing now that I fixed it.

Comment: so what do you want @weltschmerz?